# DateTime compare two dates

Tags: php, datetime

The goal is to diff two dates.

I have a DateTime object stored in my db table under timestamp column. I use Doctrine to retrieve the date, Once retrieved the date from my db it looked like this by `var_dump`;

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["timestamp"]=>
    object(DateTime)#321 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2016-08-03 11:03:36.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/London"
    }
  }
}
```

the retrieved object was assigned to a `$result` variable now to get to the `DateTime` object I did this `$result[0][timestamp]`.

To retrieve the actual data i did this `$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` according to this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

So now that i have retrieved the date a row was inserted into my db I need another date as of current time.

i.e:

```
$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = new DateTime();
$test = $date1->diff($date2);
```

diff according to this [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

this gives me this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object
```

Any idea why i get this error message looks like am doing things the right way according to the docks. Maybe there is another way do diff two dates OPP way.

**UPDATE:**

Ok so yes it is true if I use `$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` its no longer a object its a stiring.

So now my code looks like this:

$test = $result->diff(new DateTime());
var_dump($test);

it returns DateInterval object but what do i make out of it:

```
object(DateInterval)#317 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(1)
  ["i"]=>
  int(27)
  ["s"]=>
  int(5)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
```

What i need if Date1 diff to Date2 is > than 30 mins I want to take some actions.

Comment: `$result->diff($date2)`

Answer (score 2):

It is because [method format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) returns string, but not object. Try to use:

```
$test = $result->diff(new DateTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

`$date1` is now a string which doesn't have a format() method.

Try this instead:-

```
$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = new DateTime();
$test = $result->diff($date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you do `$date1 = $result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. `$date1` is no more a `DateTime` object, rather a string representation of date and time.

Hence skip this line. Don't format, and then check for difference. That will give you a `DateTimeInterval`  object.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't know what diff() does, it compares two dates and returns the difference -- but unlikely other subtraction methods, diff() never returns a negative value.  It doesn't matter if the first date is larger or smaller than the second date.

Now, if that is not a concern for this case, the next step is to access the necessary values in the DateInterval object.

```
$diff=(array)$date1->diff($date2);      // calculate the difference and cast as an array
$labels=array("y"=>"year","m"=>"month","d"=>"day","h"=>"hour","i"=>"minute");
// filter the $diff array to only include the desired elements and loop
foreach(array_intersect_key($diff,$labels) as $k=>$v){
    if(($k!="i" && $v>0) || $v>30){
        // $labels[$k] = $v > 30 minutes, take some action
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tomazi If my answer satisfies your question, please award it the green tick so that your question is removed from the unanswered questions list.  If there is still something unresolved, please explain and I'll try to help.